# Robots.txt disallow subdirectoy but allow folder within that

Tags: seo, robots.txt

Im looking to disallow a subdirectory in my root folder but allow a folder within that.

What I have:

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /admin
```

I want to allow /admin/images

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Give a try in robots.txt tester to avoid any negative impact.

```
Allow: /admin/images/
Disallow: /admin/
```